# String.format Issues

Tags: vb.net, string, string.format

I've been working with Visual basic on an assignment and i'm not overly familiar with print functions but I know enough from my reference book to understand a little how they work. The issue however doesn't seem to be with print functions as much as the string.format() function. For some reason it act's irrationally, for instance having some fields next to each other and others several spaces away. I've tried a few things such as padding and using a monospaced font but even still i get alignment issues. I'm aware that the header isn't formatted at all, i'm mainly concerned about the body at the moment since that's much more dynamic. The data is pulled from a list box that is formatted in a comma delimetered style and seems to split into substrings fine, but when put into an array and then print previewed it's apparent that the formatting is not working as I supposed it would. I've tried several different methods but to no avail. I'm sure I could figure out a work around if I need to but it seems that this function should work and maybe there's something I'm missing. Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
Private Sub mnu_file_print_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnu_file_print.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub mnu_file_print_preview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnu_file_print_preview.Click
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage



    Dim Record_Array(9) ' Array used to hold the for each word loop strings for inserting into the table.
    Dim int_loop_num As Integer = 0

    Dim str_print_body As String = String.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-20}{3,-20}{4,-20}{5,-20}{6,-15}{7,-20}{8,-20}{9,-5}", Record_Array(0) & "|", Record_Array(1) & "|", Record_Array(2) & "|", Record_Array(3) & "|", Record_Array(4) & "|", Record_Array(5) & "|", Record_Array(6) & "|", Record_Array(7) & "|", Record_Array(8) & "|", Record_Array(9) & "|")

    Dim startX As Integer = 62
    Dim startY As Integer = 62

    Dim font As New Font("Courier New", 7, FontStyle.Regular)

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Room Number,Bench Number,Make,Model,Name,Serial Number,Device Description,Device Use,State Tag,Repair", lst_print_box.Font, Brushes.Black, startX, startY - 16)

    ' for each item in the list
    For Each index As String In lst_print_box.Items
        ' for each sub string in the item
        For Each word As String In Split(index, ",")
            Record_Array(int_loop_num) = word.PadRight(5, "_").PadLeft(10, "_")
            int_loop_num += 1
        Next
        str_print_body = String.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-20}{3,-20}{4,-20}{5,-20}{6,-15}{7,-20}{8,-20}{9,-5}", Record_Array(0) & "|", Record_Array(1) & "|", Record_Array(2) & "|", Record_Array(3) & "|", Record_Array(4) & "|", Record_Array(5) & "|", Record_Array(6) & "|", Record_Array(7) & "|", Record_Array(8) & "|", Record_Array(9) & "|")

        e.Graphics.DrawString(str_print_body, font, Brushes.Black, startX, startY)
        int_loop_num = 0
        startY += lst_print_box.ItemHeight
    Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be extra spaces in result string.
Check content of variable `str_print_body` for extra spaces. If there are some, you can crop each string, e.g. change

`Record_Array(2)`   to    `Left(Record_Array(2), 20)`

Better approach would be to understand where extra spaces originate and fix the issue directly at its origin.

Comment: Oh, this worked, thank you. Though the syntax is Record_Array(2).PadLeft(10, " "). I'm not sure why it only works like that though since I tried padding it before i sent it to the array.

Comment: Please remember that `PadLeft()` does not crop input string if it is already longer than given number of characters. But some of your strings obviously needed cropping, didn't they?  Also please accept the answer by checking the green mark on the left – see the [tour].